# Potential difference across a wire along all paths

Tags: electric-current, charge, potential

I encountered a interesting problem. It first invokes the fact that between two points, potential difference is independent of the path between them. Then, it asks you to apply it for a wire carrying constant current I. Path 1: Along the wire. Path 2: Going in a curved path outside the wire. The thing is, a non zero field is needed outside the wire to evaluate (E . dr).  It hints of a surface charge density on the wire. But, I am not able to correlate it with our day to day observation or find its distribution mathematically.
[image: The two paths]

Comment: The scenario you've described is clear enough, but what exactly are you asking? How to find the surface charge on a current carrying wire? Something else?

Comment: Yes, I would like to know its distribution.  I am even confused as to how field lines are starting and ending on the same surface.

Comment: @Sarthak Rout Why do you think that field lines start and end on the same surface ?

Comment: I am taking a path, a curved one which starts on point A on the wire and ends on another point B in the wire. From A,  I leave the surface, kinda fly above it and then land on point A. So, the surface, (can assume cylindrical), is same. I will be adding a pic.

Comment: There is an electric field outside a wire. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/61884/does-a-current-carrying-wire-produce-electric-field-outside/62166#62166

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Electric field outside wire with stationary current](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/291779)

Comment: They were not quite helpful. They give reference to an article which requires paid access. I would like someone to explain it if you have it.